# Forming a JSON Data request in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, web-services, request

I have to send the following JSON data in request for a web service. So how can I create the following type of JSON using iOS/objective C:

```
{
"version": "1.0",
"myData": [
    {
        "name": "",
        "value": [
            {
                "time": "1-JAN-2013 14:30:00 IST",
                "values": [
                    {
                        "name": "",
                        "value": ""
                    }
                ]
            }]
    }]
}
```

I tried :

```
NSDictionary* version = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
  [1.0 objectForKey:@"version"], [NSArray objectForKey:@"observations"]
```

Am I missing something ?

Comment: I tend to use NSMutableDictionary *jsonDict to create the json dictionary so that I can use [jsonDict setValue:"1.0" forKey:@"version"]; or [jsonDict setValue:myDataArray forKey:@"myData"]; Your above "dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys" method expect your list to be in order of value, key, value, key. So if you want to use that method, you'd put [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: @"1.0", @"version", myDataArray, @"myData", nil];

Comment: seems to be unclear, where is  the code for `NSJSONSerialization` of NSJSon object. And what you're trying to achieve for `version`.

Comment: The above statement to be sent in my request body. I am aware that, I should create - [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:... But, my question is how to form such request body?

Answer (score 1):

Try this i am using below method

```
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dict
                                                   options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted
                                                     error:&error];
NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSMutableURLRequest* request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] ;
receivedData = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithLength:0];
[request setURL:url];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:[jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
NSURLConnection *connection= [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

[connection start];
```

Comment: i have a doubt on - NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted? Did you refer to the json typed in above or the NSDictionary thing?

Comment: I have sent the NSDictionary using this. No its fine.

Comment: This helps in understanding how to form JSON data form NSdictionary.

Answer (score 0):

```
I think it must be like this

NSArray arrObservations=[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"",@"name",arrayValue,@"value", nil]];

NSDictionary* version = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:1.0],@"version",arrayObservations,@"myData", nil];
```

Comment: This is correct, but we should add a mutable array.

Answer (score 0):

NSMutableArray *output = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSMutableDictionary *outputObjects = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                  @"temp-value",@"name",
                                  @"72.0",@"value",nil];
    [output addObject:outputObjects];

```
NSMutableArray * myData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSMutableDictionary *recordObjects = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                    @"23-JUL-2014 10:42:00 IST",@"time",
                    output,@"value",
                    nil];
[records addObject:recordObjects];


NSMutableArray *observationValues = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSMutableDictionary *observationValuesObjects = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               @"val",@"name",
                              records,@"record",nil];
[observationValues addObject:observationValuesObjects];


NSDictionary *postData = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                @"1.0.1",kPostData,
                                observationValues,@"observations",
                                nil]
```